# Show that an inequality $\|\{a_n\}\|_{L^q}\leq A\|f\|_{L^p}$ with $a_n$ the fourier coefficient,is possible only if $1/p+1/q \leq 1$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

> Show that an inequality $\|\{a_n\}\|_{L^q}\leq A\|f\|_{L^p}$,for all $f\in L^p$, with $a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\theta^{2\pi}f(\theta)e^{-inθ}d\theta$, is possible only if $1/p+1/q \leq 1$

It's an exercise from Stein's functional analysis. The hint says to use the Dirichlet kernel $D_N(\theta)=\sum_{|n|\leq N}e^{in\theta}$ and the fact that $\|D_N\|_{L^p}\approx N^{1-1/p}$ when $p>1$ and $\|D_N\|_{L^1}\approx \log N$. But I can't see what I want to prove is relevant to Dirichlet kernel. What I see is if argue by contradiction,then the pair $(p,q)$ in Riesz diagram is upon the line $x+y=1$ which seems not work.Does anyone know how to prove it？Thanks in advance

**Edit:** Clearly $D_N(\theta)$ is in $L^p$, then putting this into the inequality yields $(2N+1)^{1/q}\leq A'N^{1-1/p}$, and this only hold when $1/p+1/q \leq 1$ for sufficient large $N$. So,I think I work it out. But thank everyone all the same.

Comment: Define $f\mapsto\mathcal{D}f=(c_n(f):n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ where $c_n(f)=\int_\mathbb{S}e^{-2\pi int}f(x)\,dx$.
1. $\mathcal{D}:L_2(\mathbb{T})\rightarrow \ell_2(\mathbb{Z})$
satisfies $\|Df\|_{\ell_2}=\|f\|_{L_2(\mathbb{T}}$.
2. $\mathcal{D}:L_1(\mathbb{T})\rightarrow\ell_\infty(\mathbb{Z})$
satisfies $\|Df\|_{\ell_\infty}\leq \|f\|_1$.
By Riesz-interpolation, for $\frac{1}{p_t}=t+\frac{1-t}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{q_t}=\frac{1-t}{2}$, $0\leq t\leq 1$, $\mathcal{D}:L_{p_t}(\mathbb{T})\rightarrow\ell_{q_t}(\mathbb{Z})$ satisfies $\|\mathcal{D}f\|_{\ell_{q_t}}\leq \|f\|_{L_{p_t}}$

Comment: @OliverDiaz I think your arguement only says the inequality holds when the pair $(p,q)$ is in the lower triangle below the line $x+y=1$ in the Riesz diagram,but here the inequality is for all $p$

Comment: Just in case you are curious. The asymptotic growth of the $L_p(\mathbb{T})$-notm Dirichlet kernel $D_N$ has been studied here at MSE. The [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2031547/121671) has a couple of answers that show that $\|D_n\|_p\sim N^{1-(1/p)}$ for $p>1$. Cheers!